# Can I fit a linear mixed effects model to these grouped data?

Tags: r, mixed-model, modeling, group-differences

## Data and Objective

The data are about lane change maneuvers. I want to predict the lane change duration of a driver of certain age and gender. Following is a very small subset of observations and variables in original data:

- Dependent variable: duration of lane change (1 observation per driver).
- Independent variables: speed of vehicle (multiple obs per driver i.e. from start to end of the lane change), gender & age of driver (1 obs per driver).
  Here's a sample data frame:

---

```
    df <-  structure(list(driver = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Car1", 
    "Car2"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), speed = c(40.5, 
    40.5, 40.7, 41, 41, 38.9, 38.6, 38.8, 39, 39.1, 55, 55, 55, 55.2, 
    55.3, 25, 25.3, 25.6, 25.6, 25.7), age = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), 
        LC_maneuver = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("lane_change1", 
        "lane_change2")), status = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L
        ), .Label = c("changing lane", "End_of_LC", "Start_of_LC"
        ), class = "factor"), LC_duration = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 
        8, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)), .Names = c("driver", 
    "gender", "speed", "age", "LC_maneuver", "status", "LC_duration"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please note that each `driver` has multiple lane changes (at different locations).

## What model is appropriate for these data?

Obviously, multiple linear regression is not appropriate in this case because of both fixed and random effects. I have just started learning about the linear mixed effect models. I found [this tutorial](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf) which is really helpful for building concepts and contains r code. However, I'm confused if LME model can be used in this case. This is because my dependent variable `LC_duration` is a single value for a given `driver` and given `LC_maneuver`, but a dependent variable, `speed` is a continuous variable that varies during the duration of a lane change. So my questions are:

- Can I use LME in this case?
- If not, what other model(s) would be more appropriate in this case?